# Use RegisterStartupScript to place HTML at the bottom of the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I tried using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to place HTML or invisible elements at the bottom of my page and this seems to be working fine. Is there anything wrong with this as the `RegisterStartupScript` was intended for JavaScript only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` is the correct control to use to "place HTML or invisible elements at the bottom of my page"

Comment: The problem is the .NET CMS I am using interpets content placeholders for its own use.

Comment: Ok no problem, just use asp:Panel instead. you can add any controls into the panel. http://forums.asp.net/t/1505388.aspx/1

Comment: A placeholder worked pretty well: <asp:PlaceHolder /> Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'll most likely encounter with this approach is that when using the UpdatePanel, you should be calling `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` instead. This will depend on the structure of your page (eg, are you registing the script from within a UserControl), and what your javascript is doing

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is not something to be taken as a best practice, but I believe it should not cause you any problem. What the ScriptManager and the ClientScript do, is just append the specified content to the output HTML that is going to be sent to the browser.
However, you can consider to achieve this by placing place holder control at the bottom of the  page and then append your HTML content to that holder.